# SharePoint Search Component has multiple process and use lots memory?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I'm using sharepoint2013 + windows2012. I noticed that the SP search component has 5 processes in taskmgr. each uses about 400-500 MB memory. Is this normal? I also tried

Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -PerformanceLevel Reduced

But it did not change anything. Should I restart the server?

I never nooticed this on other SP server I worked before. Just curious, is it because of SP 2013, some default settings?

thanks

[image: taskmgr]

Answer (score 5):

user3211586 ‘s link worked for me.  Basically this article says:

**Quick and Dirty**
Kill  the noderunner.exe (Microsoft Sharepoint Search Component) process via TaskManager
This will obviously break everything related to Search on the site

**Production**
Change the Search Service Performance Level  with powerhsell

Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService –PerformanceLevel “PartlyReduced”
Performance Level Explained:

- **Reduced:** Total number of threads = number of processors, Max Threads/host = number of processors
- **PartlyReduced:** Total number of threads = 4 times the number of processors , Max Threads/host = 16 times the number of processors
- **Maximum:** Total number of threads = 4 times the number of processors , Max Threads/host = 16 times the number of processors (threads are created at HIGH priority)

For the setting to take effect do an IISReset or restart the Search Service in Central Admin

I had the same issue as the OP and running Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService –PerformanceLevel “PartlyReduced” followed by IISRESET /noforce resolved the issue for me.

Comment: [Get_SPEnterpriseSeachService Error](http://i.imgur.com/618Pvu3.png)
I got this error when trying to push Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService to PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

Please check below given article:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20413.sharepoint-2013-performance-issues-with-search-service-application.aspx

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this method, and when I changed the config setting from 0 to any value between 1 and 500, it did reduce the memory usage but the search stopped working. After I reverted back the config settings to 0, the memory usage increased but search started working again.